# how to get aws sms delivery report programmatically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns

I am using **AWS SNS** to send **SMS to mobile**.

I can see **S3 Delivery Status** upload on S3 Option is there. But for that, I have to run batch daily. The report will almost delayed.

The Second Option I can see on Cloudwatch.

Is it possible from cloudwatch we can publish SQS event with logs detail So that I can write SQS subscriber to fetch the message delivery status? or if any other option available which I have not explored so far please let me know.

I am using Java and aws-java-sdk to fetch detail.

Please Note I have gone through the document but unable to find something useful.

Any Suggestion is welcome.

Please I have gone through document but unable to find

Answer (score 2):

To get SMS delivery status you have to do the following

1. Enable 'Delivery status logging' to AWS Cloudwatch [More Info](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/monitor-sns-texts-cloudwatch/)
2. set permission for the user (used in script) to access the AWS Cloudwatch log
3. Read the log entry from cloudwatch with awssdk.

See the below PHP code which I am using in my project, you can refer this to a create java code

```html
require 'inc/awsSdkForPhp/aws-autoloader.php';
$params = array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key' => '<YOUR KEY>',
        'secret' => '<YOUR SECRET>',
    ),
    'region' => 'us-east-1', //  your aws from SNS region
    'version' => 'latest'
);
$cwClient = new \Aws\CloudWatchLogs\CloudWatchLogsClient($params);
$queryRes = $cwClient->startQuery([
  'endTime' => 1621231180,  // UNIX TIMESTAMP 
  'logGroupName' => 'sns/us-east-1/***/DirectPublishToPhoneNumber', // YOUR LOG GROUP NAME
  'queryString' => 'fields @timestamp, status, @message
  | filter notification.messageId="5a419afc-c4b3-55b3-85f9-c3e7676b2dd2"', // YOUR MESSAGE ID
  'startTime' => 1620954551 // START UNIX TIMESTAMP 
]);

$qryID = $queryRes->get('queryId');
sleep(3); // To wait the execution to be completed.
$resultObj =  $cwClient->getQueryResults(array(
  'queryId' => $qryID, // REQUIRED
));

//echo "<pre>";print_r($resultObj);echo "</pre>";
$result = $resultObj->get('results');

$jsnRs = json_decode($result[0][2]['value']); // TO get the delivery array 

echo "<br>status :".$jsnRs->status;
echo "<br>phone Carrier :".$jsnRs->delivery->phoneCarrier;
echo "<br>provider Response :".$jsnRs->delivery->providerResponse;
echo "<pre>";print_r($jsnRs);echo "</pre>";
```

I believe it will help someone

Comment: thanks for this, do you perhaps have a link to a doc describing what this returns $cwClient->getQueryResults for sns?

Answer (score 0):

we can use lamda to readlogs from awscloudwatch by watch awscloudwatch events.